# How to retain special character from a json file while reading into python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string

I have an entry in Json called J as follows:-

```
    {
     "list_1":["numeral sejío"]
```

When I am reading it into python as

```
    newlist=J.list_1
```

The result is being shown as

```
      ['numeral sejÃ\xado']
```

I want to retain the original one. Can anyone help? The issue does not occur is the list_1 declaration is in single quotes, however in a json file, cannot do it.

Comment: How much do you know about Unicode and character encodings?  It looks like the `í` was encoded using a different encoding that what you interpreted it as.  How did you read the file?  What encoding is the file encoded in?  Perhaps you need to explicitly mention UTF-8 encoding somewhere.  How did you read the file?

Comment: Note: If you need to fix problems like this later, have a look at this library that fixes it automatically. https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

try this : `json.loads(in_string).encode("latin_1").decode("utf_8")`

Comment: @sayan_sen if you are happy with the solution could you validated as the solution please